# how to deploy crystal report on client machine, in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I am working on VB.net project with Crystal report.

My problem is that, on the client's machine Crystal report forms are failing with the following error;

> Error-> "Either the crystal report registry key permissions are
>   insufficient,or the crystal reports run time is not installed
>   correctly"

Any idea how to solve the issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install crystal report viewer only to client PC, not the whole software just the viewer.

depends on client PC 64 bit or 32 bit, and the version has been developed with.